# Getting multiple objects inside json object to datagrid

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm working on a project that uses React with typescript and materialUi and I'm supposed to get data from json fetch into an DataGrid object.

JSON looks like this

```
{
  id: "1234567890",
  number: "123456789",
  description: "thingy",
  location: "im here",
  startFrom: "today",
  objects: [
    {
      stuffId: "1234567890",
      name: "this is my name",
      description: null,
      part: null,
      
    },
    {
      stuffId: "1234567890",
      name: "this is my name",
      description: null,
      part: null,
      
    }
  ]
}
```

So the problem is how to get the two objects inside the "objects" list inside the json into a  object? EDIT: this is related TS in a way that i would like to have the answer to be written with TS in mind.

Expected output in the datagrid would be that the datagrid lists both of the objects under their correct headers. (I would have liked to upload an image to explain it better but apparently i need 10 reputation and have 9 lol)

I have tried many things but none have worked, this post would be too long if i listed everything. Im getting the data correctly with my axios method into this: `const [data, setData] = useState<AxiosResponse | null>(null);`

```
const values = data?.data.objects;
```

Above code logs correct data but i cant seem to figure out how to display it in the datagrid.

Comment: You mean access the value of 'objects'

Comment: well yes, i want to get "stuffId" and "name" into datagrid

Comment: add expected output and what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```js
  const data = {
      id: '1234567890',
      number: '123456789',
      description: 'thingy',
      location: 'im here',
      startFrom: 'today',
      objects: [
        {
          stuffId: '1234567890',
          name: 'this is my name',
          description: null,
          part: null,
        },
        {
          stuffId: '1234567890',
          name: 'this is my name',
          description: null,
          part: null,
        },
      ],
    };

    const valueIwant = data.objects.map((x) => {
      const { stuffId, name } = x;
      return {
        stuffId,
        name,
      };
    });

    console.log('valueIwant', valueIwant);
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer but i tried to implement it to my code and got this: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: Try to add ? like this =>  data?.objects?.map

Comment: I did and i also got it to log data correctly to console, thanks for the help! But now, when im trying to get the data to <DataGrid> it gives me this: Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `rows` is marked as required in `ForwardRef`, but its value is `undefined`.